# 404 Page Not Found The page you requested was not found while new page created codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have copied Model, View, Controller files to new Model/Controller/View with different filename in a codeigniter project. When I access the new page the below error is occurring:

> 404 Page Not Found
>
> The page you requested was not found.

Comment: did you update the class names? are the filenames starting with an uppercase? show SHORT example of MVC, did you check routing?

Comment: class name are not updated, is it required to update? rest are okay(Uppercase etc)

Comment: well if a model's filename is MyModel.php, it needs to start with `class MyModel extends CI_Model {}`

Comment: it's like this class Model_stores_1 extends CI_Model

Comment: @Vickel sir is it rule to start `Controller`, `Model` Class Name Starts with First Letter is UpperCase?

Comment: @KUMAR yes: see https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Comment: thank you @Vickel, for the comment, Issue has been resolved.

Comment: @NaveedUlIslam I wrote a summarizing answer, with all possible causes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works fine now, Class names were not updated it have been updated now.

Answer (score 1):

if you copy (save as) a controller or model, there are several reasons why a

> 404, page not found error

may occur:

- the file was not saved with a capital first letter
- the class name was not updated
- the class name was updated, but doesn't start with a capital first letter
- in case of controller: the routing was not updated/included

for example, if a model's filename is MyModel.php, it needs to start with
`class MyModel extends CI_Model {}`

see General Topics [Controllers](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#controllers) and [Models](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html)