# Unable to load your default controller Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I use HMVC and I uploaded my site from local to online.

I have a strange error:
Unable to load your default controller. Please make sure the controller specified in your Routes.php file is valid.

on my local server works fine! So sad! I changed only base_url and database details. I shouldn't have this error...

Comment: check letters case in path to controller. If your local computer under `Windows` the path is case insensitive, but on server probably `linux` so it's case sensitive.

Comment: some of the reasons are explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63428338/2275490